# android tabhost same activity

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm going to create an activity that shows statistic. I planned to have a TabHost with two tabs, the first one displays data in a table and the second tab displays a js diagram of the same data using a webview.
So, since they share the same data and everything, I thought the easist way would be to create one activity/class and then play with the views. However, I would be delighted to get some good examples for how to do this. All I find is how it's done the opposite way, with separate activities.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is an example XML file for TabHost:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/tabhost1" style="?left_half_tabhost_holder">
    <TabHost style="?tabhost"
        <RelativeLayout style="?tabhost_countainer">
            <FrameLayout style="?tab_content">
                <ScrollView android:id="@+id/tab1" style="?tabtype_scrollview">
                    <ImageView style="?tab_content_mockup_map" android:onClick="onClickMap" />
                </ScrollView>
                <ScrollView android:id="@+id/tab2" style="?tabtype_scrollview">
                    <ImageView style="?tab_content_mockup_email" android:onClick="onClickMessages" />
                </ScrollView>
                <ScrollView android:id="@+id/tab3" style="?tabtype_scrollview">
                    <ImageView style="?tab_content_mockup_workload" android:onClick="onClickWorkload" />
                </ScrollView>
            </FrameLayout>
            <TabWidget style="?tabwidget" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code to setup the tabs:

```
private void SetupMainTabHost()
{
    View v = null;

    v = findViewById(R.id.tabhost1);
    mMainTabhost = (TabHost) v.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    mMainTabhost.setup();
    TabSpec spec = mMainTabhost.newTabSpec("tab1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    // getString(R.string.settings_tab_caption_1)
    spec.setIndicator(getString(R.string.maptabtitle));
    mMainTabhost.addTab(spec);
    spec = mMainTabhost.newTabSpec("tab2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator(getString(R.string.messagetabtitle));
    mMainTabhost.addTab(spec);
    spec = mMainTabhost.newTabSpec("tab3");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    spec.setIndicator(getString(R.string.workloadtabtitle));
    mMainTabhost.addTab(spec);
}
```

Hope this helps.